# Good alternative source control for VS2005 and 2008 instead of VSS

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I am currently using Visual SourceSafe, I do not find it easy going. What are other people using, and does it 
a) integrate into Visual Studio 2005 and 2008.
b) allow a migration path from Visual SourceSafe with full history/versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [GIT](http://www.git-scm.org) or [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Both are excellent source control systems.

We use SVN in work as there are several good clients (TortoiseSVN) for explorer and for integration with the IDE (AnkhSVN or VisualSVN)

Also search Stackoverflow for "Visual Studio" & "Source Control" or either of the above specific SCM's and you'll find plenty of other people sharing their opinions and experience with them.

Comment: +1 for SVN. Also there are a great number of same questions on SO

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of SVN - usually via TortoiseSVN (IDE integration is over-rated, IMO).

A quick search shows a [tool here](http://www.poweradmin.com/sourcecode/vssmigrate.aspx) that will move VSS into SVN with history.

For hosting; IMO, the (free) [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is unbeatable; a breeze to install (next/next/next...) - and it can use your domain accounts for access (rather than a separate user database).

Comment: I have used the migration tool, Although it's slow it will take a VSS path (which could be the root of the repository) and create a copy in SVN with all the revision history kept intact!

Answer (score 0):

What about [SourceGear's Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) ?

It uses a SQL Server database to store your projects, it has VS.NET integration, etc...
You can also convert or import your VSS databases into it.

It used to have a free license for single user licenses, but I don't know if that is still the case ...

If you would like to stay with MS tools, you could also take a look at TFS ?

Comment: +1 - Vault is a great and very useful tool - highly recommended. Free for teams up to 2 programmers, and worth every penny for larger installs.

Answer (score -1):

Team Foundation Server (TFS).

Comment: It highly depends on the size of the development team. TFS is overkill for small groups (1-3 people).

Comment: @Kent: More a case of: TFS is overkill for source control *only*. Makes more sense if you use reporting/task tracking/... as well.

Comment: I agree with Richard...TFS is great if you wan´t more than just source control (even though it has a great source control system that can handle "upgrades" from VSS). :-)

Answer (score -2):

svn is bad idea. most big teams already migrate from them.

I prefer GNU Bazaar and git. Monotone also is good choice but I do not know which of them compatible with Visual studio